# Best way to display image in grid view is scrolling smooth

Tags: android, performance, bitmap

First of all, I have already done few things to display image in gridview make smooth when scrolling

**1. load image from internet on background thread**

```
AsyncTask acyncTask ;
HandlerThread handlerThread ;

 URL imageUrl = new URL(link);<br>
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)imageUrl.openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
            conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            InputStream is=conn.getInputStream();
            final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
```

**2. make bitmap to sample size to save memory**

```
final BitmapFactory.Options option = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    option.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mFile.getPath(),
            option);
    option.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(option , mSize , mSize);
    option.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    option.inPurgeable = true ;
    option.inDither = false ;
    option.inScaled = false ;
    option.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
```

**3. make a cache to save decoded bitmap**

```
LruCache lruCache = new LruCache<String , Bitmap>();
```

in `baseadapter getView();`
I will `lruCache.get(key)` to take the decoded bitmap

**4. lazy load when bitmap decoded through handler**

```
 Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.post(new Runnable(){
           public void run(){
              imageView.setimageBitmap(bitmap);
          }
      });
```

Now I am facing a big problem, it still lag a bit when I'm scrolling 
i have google about something can make the **scrolling better**, don't know really something can improve or the problem is come out from where i have check for each getView() only spend me about **2~6ms** and it will call my code to **async loading the image form worker thread**, so i really don't know why **some apps can loading very smooth**? my case is **when scrolling** the screen will not look like very smooth is it some suggestion can apply?

edited : when i am scrolling , the bitmap found in cache and display on the screen , if i fast scroll , it will look like no scroll enough to show the image , it will make my scroll not so smooth , even i have cache down the bitmap in cache

here is the adapter code :

```
if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(
                R.layout.row_display_image_grid, null);
        viewHolder = new DisplayImageGridViewHolder();
        viewHolder.background = (RelativeLayout) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.background);
        viewHolder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        viewHolder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
        viewHolder.position = position;
        viewHolder.text.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.END);
        viewHolder.text.setTypeface(typeFace);
        viewHolder.image.setOnClickListener(this);
        viewHolder.image.setOnLongClickListener(this);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (DisplayImageGridViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

viewHolder.position = position;
imageLoader.loadImage(imageLinkList.get(position), viewHolder.image);
return convertView;
```

Comment: Can you post your adapter code, specifically the getView() method. That is most likely where the scrolling lag will be coming from.

Comment: have added , i just call a method to start the loading task at a worker thread , i have check before and after this getview method , it only spend my fews mills seconds , do you think setimagebitmap is something problem when scrolling gridview

Comment: Your code is still a little unclear. Can you post your entire ImageLoader class. I am using very similar code, possibly based on the same example and have it working with no lag.

Comment: oh i see , you are using the similar one , how about you how to display the image on gridview ?? if you scroll fast , is a will be a little bit lag ?? 
i just change the showing bitmap method from runonuithread to handler postdelayed , else is same .

Comment: I just use AsyncTasks to load the images. Load the image from the web / local storage / memory in doInBackground. Then set the image in onPostExecute.

Comment: you doesn't have some little bit lag while fasr scroll ??

Comment: No there is none. Are you sure you aren't performing any tasks on the UI thread. Are you downloading the bitmap in the asynctask? Your code above doesn't make it clear, but it looks like you are downloading on the UI thread.

Comment: btw i am using exectur service to load the image , so i will not be doing something on ui thread .....just i am finding someway to improve the display speed on gridview

Answer (score 4):

Below is an example of the LazyLoader I use. Note I am using SoftReferences for bitmaps, this is now better served by using `LruCache`.

This will load an image asynchronously from the web / sdcard / memory and create a fade in effect from a placeholder image.

```
public class ImageLoader {

private static MemoryCacheNew memoryCache=new MemoryCacheNew();
private static FileCache fileCache;

private static BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions;

private static int mInSampleSize;



public ImageLoader(Context context, int inSampleSize){


    fileCache=new FileCache(context);        

    context = null;

    bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bitmapOptions.inSampleSize = mInSampleSize = inSampleSize;
    bitmapOptions.inPreferredConfig = Config.RGB_565;
    bitmapOptions.inInputShareable = true;
    bitmapOptions.inDither = false;

}

final static int PLACEHOLDER_IMAGE = R.drawable.store_placeholder;

public void DisplayImage(String url, ImageView imageView,  boolean checkTags){

    try{

    new AsyncPhotoTask(imageView, url, checkTags).execute();

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void DisplayImage(String url, ImageView imageView)
{
      DisplayImage(url, imageView, true); 

}


private static Bitmap getBitmap(String url) 
{
    File f=fileCache.getFile(url);


    if(f!= null){
    //from SD cache
    Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
    if(b!=null)
        return b;
    }

    //from web
    try {
        Bitmap bitmap=null;

        URL imageUrl;

            imageUrl = new URL(url);


        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)imageUrl.openConnection();
        conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
        conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
        InputStream is=conn.getInputStream();
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
        Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
        is.close();
        os.close();
        bitmap = decodeFile(f);
        return bitmap;
    } catch (Exception ex){
       ex.printStackTrace();
       return null;
    }
}

//decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
private static Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
    try {
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, bitmapOptions);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

    } catch (OutOfMemoryError err){
        System.gc();
    } 

    return null;
}


private static class AsyncPhotoLoad extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, TransitionDrawable>{

    private Bitmap bmp;
    private ImageView imageView;
    private String url;
    private boolean checkTags;

    public AsyncPhotoLoad(ImageView imageView, String url, boolean checkTags
            ){
        this.imageView = imageView;
        this.url = url;
        this.checkTags = checkTags;
    }

    @Override
    protected TransitionDrawable doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

        //check that this is the correct imageview



        TransitionDrawable transition = null;

        try{
            if(checkTags){
            String tag = (String)imageView.getTag();    
            if(!tag.equals(url))
                return null;
            }

        bmp = getBitmap(url);

        if(bmp != null){
            memoryCache.put(url, bmp, mInSampleSize);    

            Drawable oldDrawable = imageView.getDrawable();

            if(!(oldDrawable instanceof TransitionDrawable)){

                Drawable layers[] = new Drawable[2];                    
                layers[0] = imageView.getDrawable();
                layers[1] = new BitmapDrawable(bmp);

               transition = new TransitionDrawable(layers);

            }



        }

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return transition;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(TransitionDrawable result) {
        if(result != null){
            try{            
                if(checkTags){                      
                        String tag = (String)imageView.getTag();    
                        if(!tag.equals(url)){
                            return;
                        }
                }

                   imageView.setImageDrawable(result);
                   result.startTransition(300);



            } catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            if(checkTags){
            try{
                String tag = (String)imageView.getTag();    
                if(!tag.equals(url))
                    return;

            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            }


        }
    }

}



private static class AsyncPhotoTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap>{

    private ImageView imageView;
    private String url;
    private boolean checkTags;


    public AsyncPhotoTask(ImageView imageView, String url, boolean checkTags){

        this.imageView = imageView;
        this.url = url;
        this.checkTags = checkTags;
    } 


    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try{
        if(checkTags)
            imageView.setTag(url);  

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return memoryCache.get(url, mInSampleSize);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        try{
        if(result!=null && !result.isRecycled()){


            imageView.setImageBitmap(result);   
        }
        else
        {   

            imageView.setImageResource(PLACEHOLDER_IMAGE);            
            new AsyncPhotoLoad(imageView, url, checkTags).execute();      

        }    

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



}





public static void clearCache() {
    memoryCache.clear();
    fileCache.clear();
}

public static void clearMemory(){
    memoryCache.clear();
}

public static class MemoryCacheNew {
    private HashMap<String, CachedBitmap> cache=new HashMap<String, CachedBitmap>();

    public Bitmap get(String id, int sampleSize){
        if(!cache.containsKey(id))
            return null;

        if(cache.get(id) == null)
            return null;

        if(cache.get(id).sampleSize != sampleSize)
            return null;

        SoftReference<Bitmap> ref = cache.get(id).softBitmap;
        return ref.get();
    }

    public void put(String id, Bitmap bitmap, int sampleSize){
        cache.put(id, new CachedBitmap(bitmap, sampleSize));
    }

    public void clear() {
        cache.clear();
    }



    private static class CachedBitmap {
        public SoftReference<Bitmap> softBitmap;
        public int sampleSize;

        public CachedBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int sampleSize){
            this.softBitmap = new SoftReference<Bitmap>(bitmap);
            this.sampleSize = sampleSize;
        }
    }
}


}


public class FileCache {

private File cacheDir;

public FileCache(Context context){
    //Find the dir to save cached images
    if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
        cacheDir=new File(context.getExternalCacheDir(),Consts.STORE_CACHE);
    else
        cacheDir=context.getCacheDir();
    if(!cacheDir.exists())
        cacheDir.mkdirs();
}

public File getFile(String url){
    //I identify images by hashcode. Not a perfect solution, good for the demo.
    String filename=String.valueOf(url.hashCode());
    File f = new File(cacheDir, filename);
    return f;

}

public void clear(){
    File[] files=cacheDir.listFiles();
    for(File f:files)
        f.delete();
}

}
```

You call it like this:

```
imageLoader.DisplayImage(url, holder.image);
```

Comment: yes , you are also using the similar code , but it can't help me , sorry

Answer (score 0):

Try to make sure that each bitmap optimally sized... they should be about the size of the container. Scale them down as much as you can before sending them through RemoteViews. You can compute the widget size using onAppWidgetOptionsChanged.

Also, try using setImageViewUri (with a content provider) instead of setImageViewBitmapfor the most optimal performance.